# How much clearance is required or recommended for wifi module

Tags: networking, wifi, case

I'm making a metal container for to enclose all my components including raspberry pi 3 -B, motor controllers and batteries. I wanted to know if on board wifi module requires clearance or distance from metals in order to avoid shielding. I have mounted my raspberry pi on a acrylic sheet using brass screw pillars. One of these pillars is very close to the wifi antenna. Does it have any effect on wifi signal strength?

[image: Raspbeery Pi mounted on Brass Pillars]

Answer (score 1):

The wavelength is ~125mm so anything within this distance will affect the radiation pattern, but if you are going to put the whole thing in a [Faraday cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage) this is irrelevant, as you will prevent all radiation (depending on the quality of the shielding).

Comment: So if I want to enclose my system inside a metallic casing like a PC it would block wifi signals? how about if I provide holes (larger than 125mm) near wifi antenna of raspberry pi?

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullah What do you want me to say that isn't covered by the Wiki article? It depends; design of effective Faraday cages is a specialist area. The performance is more dependent on the conductivity between joints and leakage on any cables entering the cage. Large holes will have lower attenuation, and joint performance is influenced by other aspects e.g. the ¼λ stub used in microwave oven doors.